# SE Tag Appropriation: A list of tags to keep an eye on for potential migrations

Tags: discussion

We've come up with a list of SE links to check for questions that - if they don't have answers and they have GD potential - could be asked to be migrated to our site.

This will not only help those in search for answers lost in the wrong places, but also improve our daily question average, and bring more people to the site.

Questions are ordered by date. If you see one you think could be migrated, flag it and add a comment explaining we'd like it for GD ("We'd love this question for GD.SE! Thanks!"). As we are in beta, we don't appear in the migration lists yet, so it's important you clarify it in the flag.

SO:

- [Tagged Illustrator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/adobe-illustrator) - [Contains Illustrator](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=illustrator+is%3Aquestion)
- [Tagged Photoshop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/photoshop) - [Contains Photoshop](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=photoshop%20is%3aquestion)
- [Tagged Gimp](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=graphic%20design%20is%3aquestion) - [Contains Inkscape](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=inkscape%20is%3aquestion)
- [Contains Graphic Design](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=graphic%20design%20is%3aquestion)

UX:

- [Contains Color](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/color)

SUPERUSER:

- [Contains Photoshop](https://superuser.com/search?q=photoshop+is%3Aquestion)
- [Contains Illustrator](https://superuser.com/search?tab=newest&q=illustrator%20is%3aquestion)

Feel free to edit and add other queries we might find useful!

Comment: Just be careful only to be migrating questions that are **off topic** on the source site. If they are a good fit for the other site, they should stay there, even if they aren't answered yet. If they are off-topic on the source site and solidly on topic for GDSE, grab 'em! There's good guidance on migration policies in [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/03/respect-the-community-your-own-and-others/) for reference.

Comment: @AbbyT.Miller Thank you Abby! Yes, we are only migrating questions that are off-topic in the original sites. Very nice link!